# What is faster on GPU? Typecasting bool to int or using a branch statement?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I am trying to use CUDA in order to parallelize the simulated annealing algorithm. The GPU I am using is NVIDIA GTX660. I am trying to speed the program up and in order to do so I am considering to replace this

```
int r= rand();
if (condition) 
{
       r += 1;
}
```

with

```
int r = rand() + (condition)*1;
```

I understand that jump/branch instructions(like if-then-else commands) are the slowest to execute but unless my understanding is incorrect typecasting involves memory access then copying the number in new location as an int before accessing it. Could the result of 'condition' be stored in a register and fed in ALU without modification? if so wouldn't that be a faster way to calculate the value of variable r? The above runs on every thread.

Comment: What happened when you measured it?

Comment: It might be quicker if you (or the optimiser) remove the `*1`. But putting `(condition)` in brackets in the second example does not make it evaluate as a boolean value.

Comment: I haven't measured it. I was asking for feedback in case someone has done so before as I haven't gotten to that part of the code yet. 

Also thank you for the suggestion to remove the multiplication part. If the value i am multiplying it with is 1 it should be faster as was suggested.

Comment: Ah, I was reading `condition` as a variable, but I guess now it's your shorthand for a boolean expression. If so, in the second case, there will still be a branch instruction generated. Perhaps there is an arithmetical way of extracting the boolean result, for example `(value & 1)`.

Comment: That's not how typecasting works. The compiler generates different instructions for ints, floats, etc. When you cast, you're just telling the compiler which instruction variant - integer add, float add, etc. - to use. No copy is performed.

Comment: Hmm. So if i type r= rand() +(x comparison with y) it will branch to what in memory? Thanks again

Comment: @DavidLively - that's not necessarily true.  If the representation changes (e.g. `int` -> `float`), then a copy may well be generated.

Comment: In a release build with optimization enabled, a simple conditional increment like this should translate either to a predicated integer add, or to a select instruction (basically, `r = (cond) ? (r + 1) : r`). You can double-check by inspecting SASS (machine code) with `cuobjdump --dump-sass`. My recommendation is to write code in a natural style, and let the compiler worry about branch-conversion,

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, of course - floats can't simply be treated as ints. That whole mantissa/exponent thing gets in the way. I admit my explanation was very, very simplistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you'd try very hard to avoid branching on GPUs, since that's classically the point where the CPU needs to halt all threads that don't go through that branch, execute those who do, then halt these, and do the other branch.

That being said, the branching doesn't happen because you write `if`; it happens because you use e.g. `<` which assigns a value to a register based on what you're comparing, but that is very very depending on your actual condition, and the language/architecture you're on – my knowledge is from first-generation CUDA and might not fully apply anymore.